# Autocomplete suggestions in a form using API (WP)

Tags: wordpress, forms, api, autocomplete, wordpress-rest-api

I have an API called Aviationstack, that gives a complete list of airport names their IATA codes, and their country. I have used the crocoblock JetEngine plug-in to create a REST API and then used a way of making an autocomplete for a search form, where customers have to answer from where to where they have flown. I got it to work but it only displays the airport name and not the other elements. I have contacted crocoblock and they told me that’s how their plug-in worked and there was nothing they could do (which I doubt). Anyways I need a way to resolve this issue and i’m open for eveyrthing.

The page I need help with: https://www.flydaekning.dk/soeg-kompensation/